# How to change number of column of a gridview at same visible item. Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am writing an android app where I am using a grid view to display some items. I want to give users a configurable view where they can change the no of columns on the activity by clicking floating action button. I am changing the column no using

```
gridView.setNumColumns(selectedColumnNo);
```

This is working fine But the problem is if a user changes no of column after some scrolling the First Visible Position is set to the first item of the array list, so the user has to scroll the view again. Can someone please tell me where I am doing wrong. Or Is this the proper way to do this or should I use a different approach.

A code snippets will be helpful
Thanks.
**Update::**
currently I am using the bellow snippets

```
findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int firstPosition = gv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            if(gv.getNumColumns()==2)
            {
                gv.setNumColumns(1);
                gv.setSelection(firstPosition);
            }
            else {

                gv.setNumColumns(2);
                gv.setSelection(firstPosition);
            }


        }
    });
```

Now the problem is on every 4th switch grid view is showing the first element of the arraylist

Comment: What is `pr`? I don't understand what you're trying to do with this new code, and it sounds an awful lot like it's way out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: I am trying to keep track how many times the fab button is pressed. If it is pressed odd no of times no of column will be 1. otherwise no of column will be 2

Comment: This has nothing to do with your original problem, and frankly the mistake you've made is very basic; you're more than capable of figuring it out. If you absolutely cannot, you should open a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before you call `setNumColumns()`, save the GridView's first visible position:

```
int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Then, after you change the number of columns, pass that integer to `setSelection()`:

```
gridView.setSelection(firstPosition);
```

"Selection", counter-intuitively, is not the same thing as "activation". It will ensure that the view is on-screen, but not visibly affect it in any other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sigmabeta  It solved my problem but now I am getting an another. I have updated the question Please take a look.